# php function doesn't write to file at in on server

Tags: javascript, php, fwrite

I have this button:

```
<button onclick="writeToServer();" >Test</button>
```

The JS writeToServer() function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function writeToServer(){
    DATA = "test";
    var url = "write.php";
    var XML = "file.txt";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
        xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send("D="+DATA+'&F='+XML);
    }
</script>
```

and a **write.php** file is:

```
<?php
$NAME = $_POST['F'];
$HANDLE = fopen($NAME, 'w') or die ('CANT OPEN FILE');
fwrite($HANDLE,$_POST["D"]);
fclose($HANDLE);
?>
```

But after clicking button, **file.txt** is still empty. 
What am I doing wrong / what shoud I change to make this work.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the correct folder?

Comment: BTW, `fopen+fwrite+fclose` can be combined into `file_put_contents`.

Comment: i think i am sure, i have write.php index.html and file.txt all in same folder

Comment: You're not displaying the output of the AJAX request, are you sure it's not getting an error? Check the response in the Network tab of the browser.

Comment: BTW, it's 2020, no need to still use `ActiveXObject`.

Comment: oh, i am getting an error `POST http://127.0.0.1:38575/write.php 404 (Not Found)` but I am sure that I have this file in same directory

Comment: should I link it somehow?

Comment: You obviously don't have it in the same directory in the web root. You need to copy it there.

Comment: When I type `http://127.0.0.1:38575/write.php` into browsing bar, it starts downloading the file, so I am sure this file is here

Comment: Maybe something in .htaccess is blocking POST? Check your server log to see what the difference is.